# How to build a custom circle counter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build a circle counter using pure CSS and javascript like the below one.

[image]

Once the circle is fulfilled with the border, then it repeats from the beginning.

I put the whole border image as the background of layer A and added a new layer B on it. And tried to control the linear gradient of layer B like this,

```
background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),
    linear-gradient(-30deg, white 50%, transparent 50%)
```

but it only worked for half the circle.

Comment: So do u want the transition like countdown timer?

Comment: you could use a counter, transform and animation-delay , also using sass to create your rules in a loop : here is an example via pure CSS using sass to create the rules instead writing them one by one example with a 60 seconds counter https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yLLXOvV

Comment: .. another older example with animation only https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vmGCb hopes this helps you